# New custom post not showing after using array for Sorting by number of votes

Tags: php, wordpress

I used [wp ulike](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ulike/) in my site to add vote function per custom post.

I really need to know how can I display the new custom post in my site. All post are showing at first but after I sort it with the code given in [How To Sort Most Liked Posts?](https://github.com/alimir/wp-ulike#how-to-sort-most-liked-posts), new post is not showing. Only the posts showing is the one created before using the sorting code.

here’s my current code

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'ico',
    'post_status' => 'published',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => '_liked',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'sponsored',
            'value' => '0',
            'compare' => '==' // not really needed, this is the default
        )
    )
);
```

sorry for the grammar. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is your new post published?

Comment: @Pyromonk, yes it is published!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the new post is published and add "numberposts = -1" like so:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'ico',
    'post_status' => 'published',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => '_liked',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'sponsored',
            'value' => '0',
            'compare' => '==' // not really needed, this is the default
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Still new post doesnt show. If i removed the orderby and meta_key, it shows up. but after putting it back, it doesnt show anymore

Comment: @UrekMazino This means perhaps your new post most likely has a different key-value pair from those in your meta query.